# set tab bar items programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar, whose items I want to change depending on a user's settings. So I need to be able to add/remove items from the tab bar programmatically. Here is my code:

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
var controllerArray = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let controller1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Navigation2") as! nav2
    let controller2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Explore") as! ExploreNavigation
    let controller3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("friends") as! ExploreNav
    let controller4 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controller3ID") as! controller3VC
    controllerArray.append(controller1)
    controllerArray.append(controller2)
    controllerArray.append(controller3)
    controllerArray.append(controller4)
   self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers(controllerArray, animated: true)

  }


}
```

but if I comment out one of the lines, for example like this:

```
     //controllerArray.append(controller2)
```

so that that controller is not apart of the controllersArray, the controller still displays in the tab bar. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried this, and it didn't work either:

```
 self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = controllerArray
```

Comment: Do you want to change the items in the tab bar or the view controllers in the tab bar controller or both? You title suggests one, but your question suggests the other.

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand the difference between the view controller in the tab bar and a tab bar item. the tab bar item means the logo inside the tab bar? What I am saying is that I want the 4th (last tab) to have a different logo/image and a different view controller inside the 4th tab. I hope that is clear.

Comment: This code makes no sense. Your `TabBarViewController` extends `UITabBarController` but it also seems to have a property of type `UITabBarController`. It should be one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just say

```
self.setViewControllers(controllerArray, animated: true)
```

instead of

```
self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers(controllerArray, animated: true)
```

You are subclassing UITabBarController not UIViewController so you don't have, or at least don't need, the property tabBarController.